# Hurdle with inheritance in Java

Tags: java

I dont understand the program below. I have mentioned the two errors I have encountered in the code. But I cannot understand the reason

```
import java.io.*;
class sdata
{
    float per;
    int m,tm=0,i,n;

    sdata(int n)throws Exception
    {
       DataInputStream dis2=new DataInputStream(System.in);
       for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
       {
        System.out.print("enter marks of subject"+i);
        int m=Integer.parseInt(dis2.readLine());
        tm=tm+m;
       }
       per=tm/n;
    }
}

class disdata extends sdata
{
    //below line gives an error "constructor sdata in class xyz.sdata cannot be applied to given types required:int found:no arguments"

    disdata() throws Exception{             
      System.out.println("TOTAL MARKS OF SUBJECTS:"+tm);
      System.out.println("PERCENTAGE OF STUDENT:"+per);
    }

}
class sresult
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws  Exception
    {
       DataInputStream dis=new DataInputStream(System.in);
       int n=Integer.parseInt(dis.readLine());

       disdata objj=new disdata();
       //the below line creates an error saying "cannot find symbol" 
       objj.sdata(n);
    }
}
```

Comment: Additionally, it might be useful to read up on [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). Sticking to these will allow both people on stackoverflow and anyone needing to use / change your code to quickly understand what you were doing ;)

Comment: oh okie.. il surely do that from next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sdata` is super class of `disdata` and when you are creating a object of disdata with no argument and in `disdata` constructor you did not call `sdata` int constructor so by default it will try to find no argument `sdata` constructor, which is not available, so it gives error.

you can do thing call `sdata` int constructor from `disdata` constructor or crate a no argument constructor in `sdata`.

```
class sdata {
    float per;
    int m, tm = 0, i, n;
    sdata(int n) throws Exception {...}
    //No argument constructor
    sdata(){}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

if your `super class` has an `overloaded argument constructor` your subclass has to make a call `explicitly`.

```
disdata() throws Exception{             
     super(some int vale youwanna pass);
            System.out.println("TOTAL MARKS OF SUBJECTS:"+tm);
        System.out.println("PERCENTAGE OF STUDENT:"+per);
    }
```

remember that `super()` should be the `first line` in the `disdata() constructor`.

```
disdata objj=new disdata();
    //the below line creates an error saying "cannot find symbol" 
        objj.sdata(n);
```

`constructor` are not methods. you are trying to call the constructor sdata(n) with objj which is wrong. use new operator to invoke it .
like:

```
disdata objj=new disdata(n);
```

Comment: If is write in my code //disdata objj=new disdata(n); then will i have to rewrite the constructor of disdata like             
    disdata(int j){
       super(j);
            System.out.println("TOTAL MARKS OF SUBJECTS:"+tm);
        System.out.println("PERCENTAGE OF STUDENT:"+per);
    }

Answer (score 1):

Java enforces proper chaining of constructors.  The first statement in the body of a constructor must be either `this(...)` (a call to another constructor of the same class) or `super(...)` (a call to a superclass constructor), and if you don't include an explicit call then Java inserts an implicit call to `super()` before the rest of the constructor body.  Since your `sdata` doesn't have a no-argument constructor this fails to compile.

You need to either

1. Add a no-argument constructor to `sdata` or
2. Put a `super(0)` call as the first thing in the `disdata` constructor to call the existing single-argument superclass constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot invoke a constructor as a normal method, which you try to do with `objj.sdata(n);`.
Constructors are no methods.